# Why does my drawing disappear from a canvas?

Tags: java, android, canvas, ondraw

I perform some drawing on a canvas every 10 sec. Unfortunately it disappears before it will be redrawn, so we have 10 sec with a blank screen. I tired to save a canvas before drawing and restore it, did not help. 
This bug was appeared after I had shifted a line `canvas.drawPath(linePath, linePaint);` from outside of a loop into the loop.

**CODE:**

```
private void drawLine(Canvas canvas) {
        yStep = (yHeight) / fullChargeLevel;
        xStep = (xWidth) / timeStampBarsQuantity;

        boolean check = false;
        float time;
        float chrg;

        while (batteryUsageHistory != null && batteryUsageHistory.moveToNext()) {
            int charge = batteryUsageHistory.getInt(1);
            int time_stamp = batteryUsageHistory.getInt(2);

            if (charge < 1) {

                if(check){
                    canvas.drawPath(linePath, linePaint); //This line I shifted into here
                    linePath.reset();
                }

                check = false;

                continue;
            }

            time = xPos + time_stamp * xStep;
            chrg = yPos - (charge * yStep);

            if (!check) {
                linePath.moveTo(time, chrg);
                check = true;

                continue;
            }
            linePath.lineTo(time, chrg);
        }
        //canvas.drawPath(linePath, linePaint); //This line I shifted from here
    }
```

Comment: You get a new `Bitmap` from which you should make a new `Canvas` in each `onDraw` call, and draw on that canvas instead of saving the old one, or just draw on the new Canvas provided to you by the `onDraw(Canvas newCanvas)` method.

Comment: @Shark thank you, your answer kinda put me in a right way of thinking. I just moved back that line `canvas.drawPath(linePath, linePaint);` I was previously moved.

Comment: Saving/restoring canvas isn't actually for saving it for later use - it's used mainly before applying a transformation/rotation, doing something, then restoring it back to what it was - all in a single onDraw() call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just moved back that line `canvas.drawPath(linePath, linePaint);` I was previously moved. And it works!.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement your drawing logic in onDraw by extending some View class:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
   // here goes your custom drawing logic
}
```

as stated in: https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html

it is because android redraws the component when it needs to. It is always like that you need to implement the drawing method and the GUI framework will call this method when neccessary, it is not the opposite, that the GUI framework displays your painting, it is just calling your painting method when needed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but  I did `public class ChartView extends View implements BatteryChargeChangeListener { .//some code.. }`, and I have `onDraw` method which calls `private void drawLine(Canvas canvas)`.

Comment: please then show your code, without it I couldn't help you :)